# deduplicate multiple large files

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, word-list, bigdata

I have at least 500 different files containing words (each word in separate line). Problem is that these lists are very long (5bln records total) and I have problem making each list unique. I'd like to preserve filenames but in the same time have unique entries in every file (without merging etc).

So far I tried different programs like app.merge and ccr, DB with unique column in table (postgresql and sqlite) without a luck. Can't find reliable solution. What would be your suggestion to do that?

**EDIT**: I'm trying to prevent any files from having common words. To explain it better, let's say I have 3 files with following content:

```
f1:
word1
other
something

f2:
word2
word1
other

f3:
word1
something
myentry
```

As a result I'd expect to see:

```
f1:
word1
other
something

f2:
word2

f3:
myentry
```

Of course files itself are much much bigger (take this one as a example: http://md5decrypt.net/Telecharger-wordlist/Md5decrypt-awesome-wordlist.7z). To answer question 'what I tested so far' - well, here is my code which I'm working on now: https://pastebin.com/Y8HutakU and here is the result (stopped after 1hour of running): https://pastebin.com/tknve7qA. I know the code is far from being optimal and it's clearly visible in output where next insert to DB takes longer and longer as DB is growing. I'm experimenting with DB because I think it will be good solution for having all words unique, preserve filenames and to have comparision method for future use (when I download another wordlist to compare etc). Plus there are good writeups about SQLite performance:

- http://www.sami-lehtinen.net/blog/sqlite3-performance-testing
- https://sites.google.com/site/samilehtinenps/blog/sqlite3-python32-100-million-rows-1-million-row-read-write-test

Comment: Are you trying to prevent any two files from having a word in common, or are you just trying to make sure that the words in each file are unique within that file? If it's the latter, why does it matter how many files there are or what the total number of words is? Also what went wrong with the other solutions?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent any files from having common words.

Comment: So are all the words within each file already unique? How many distinct words do you think there are in total?

Comment: I'm affraid they are not unique but I can make them with "sort | uniq". I can't tell how many words are out there but if 500 files takes around 100GB of disk space then perhaps I could estimate it somehow. 10 characters as a average word + '\n' at the end of each line etc.

Comment: Make each file only have unique words (vesche's answer looks like it will do the trick) and your problem will probably become much smaller.

Comment: Even if I do that, I could end up with let's say 50GB of data. And this is not easy to load to DB for future referrence. I will obtain another bigh file and I will have to cross-reference it somehow with current estate.

Comment: Each one of your files will become smaller. What do you have to lose?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Linux system, you could just use standard command line tools.

```
for file in /path/to/files/*
do
    echo "`sort -u $file`" > $file
done
```

Comment: This will not solve the problem. Like I said in comment above - I'm trying to prevent any files from having common words. Following your idea I would have to use 'uniq -d' to save all duplicates to single file and then use that file as a referrence to deduplicate others. Even though, this would take ages to complete (tried that already) and it's hard to call it reliable solution when I add a file or two to that directory (whole process will have to start again)

Comment: You should better define your initial post then, it stated you wanted 'unique entries in every file' which was the solution I posted.